# Kernel hangs after running opencv image show program

Tags: python, opencv

Hi I am running a simple opencv program to load an image, and then display it.

I first used Jupyter Notebook to run it, and it runs fine the first time, but then the cell keeps processing (*) and refuses to be interrupted or run the same program again.

I assumed it might be an IDE issue, so I tried running the same program in Spyder, and again, the first run is fine but after I close the window and try to re-run, nothing happens. No errors, no crashes no warnings. Just an unresponsive state.

Why would this be happening?

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
#Load an image into img variable
img = cv2.imread('setup.PNG', 1)
#Display image
cv2.imshow('Original', img)
#These two lines of delay are necessary to make this run or it crashes
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have tried using the stop run button in Spyder and also interrupting Kernel in Jupyter notebook.

EDIT: It seems giving cv2.waitKey a numeric argument helps with the programs hanging. But now if I give a delay of 5000, it shows the image for 5 seconds and then closes. I'm curious why 0 delay does not work on my pc even though it works for others on the forums.

Comment: This is an issue with OpenCV's functionality depending on how the code is run. Note that OpenCV's display functionality is limited and is not considered part of the core library; it's just a debugging and development tool. If you run the code via command line, you'll likely not have any issues---but running it in an interpreter can create these problems.

Comment: You can also use matplotlib to visualize your matrices, but have in mind that matplotlib takes RGB and not BGR like OpenCV

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Thank you for answering, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @api55 Yes I did try that as well! Quite neat.